# Program won't break on fields (input) "9-16" (barbara), but only on field 76. Any suggestions?

Tags: java, break

The program on fields 9 - 16 will not break, but it will break on fields 76-83.
Code:

```
public class Main {
    private static String input = "p2ce9unfvbarbarbara2ehv29p4hrv2rn8h2cyr12gxbarsdg34rbarabarabarbarbarbarbarasdfgsfhhr"; // 
    private static int index = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char c;
        while (true) {
            c = nextChar();
            if (c == 'b') {
                c = nextChar();
                if (c == 'a') {
                    c = nextChar();
                    if (c == 'r') {
                        c = nextChar();
                        if (c == 'b') {
                            c = nextChar();
                            if (c == 'a') {
                                c = nextChar();
                                if (c == 'r') {
                                    c = nextChar();
                                    if (c == 'a') {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(index);

    }


    public static char nextChar() {
        return input.charAt(index++);
    }

}
```

I am new to Java as well as programming in general. The program should break after the entered input in case "barbara" is written. In the above case, it breaks only on field 76 but not on field 9 - 16.

Comment: @f1sh, No, it will never find the term, not even once. Just use the debugger to see what it does.

Comment: After you've read the first "barbar", you find a "b", so you contine the loop, but you should be backtracking to have a chance to match "barbara".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use methods from the `String` class?

A possibility would be to take the `indexOf(String str)` methods to get an index.

Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

After you've read the first "barbar", you find a "b", so you contine the loop, but you should be backtracking to have a chance to match "barbara":

```
    char c;
    while (true) {
        c = nextChar();
        if (c == 'b') {
            int savedIndex = index;
            c = nextChar();
            if (c == 'a') {
                c = nextChar();
                if (c == 'r') {
                    c = nextChar();
                    if (c == 'b') {
                        c = nextChar();
                        if (c == 'a') {
                            c = nextChar();
                            if (c == 'r') {
                                c = nextChar();
                                if (c == 'a') {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            index = savedIndex;
        }
    }
```